# Differences when using windrose (circular) and windRose (openair)

Tags: r, gis

I want to create wind roses (actually, oceanic current roses), and I'm trying the functions of the circular and openair packages. When using the windRose(openair) function, I get the results that I expect (I checked them manually), but when I use windrose(circular) I get the result that I expect for one dataset, but not for the other one. I know that meteorologists plot the direction that the wind is blowing from, and we in oceanography plot the direction where the current is heading. At first, I tried to add 180° (or pi, if I was working in radians), and it worked for one dataset, but not for the other one. I know the predominant directions of both datasets, because I'm also using variance ellipses and mean direction vectors. I actually noted that roses from windrose(circular) and ellipses don't agree. 
I would like to use windrose(circular) rather than windRose(openair), because I already modified the function to create maps with roses on certain longitude,latitude points.
I have an .RData file with the datasets, but I can't find a way to upload it to this post.

Any help is greatly aprreciatted.
Cheers.

```
#dataset1, $t is theta (direction) and $r is radius (magnitude)

windrose(data.frame(dir=circular(pol.ex$t, units="degrees"), 
mag=pol.ex$r), template="geographics") #in this dataset, predominant 
#direction is around 120°, windrose is not accurate.

rose <- windRose(mydata=data.frame(wd=pol.ex$t, ws=pol.ex$r), cols="jet", 
paddle=F) #this rose is accurate.

#dataset2, $t is theta (direction) and $r is radius (magnitude)

windrose(data.frame(dir=circular(pol.noex$t, units="degrees"), 
mag=pol.noex$r), template="geographics") #now, this one is accurate.

rose <- windRose(mydata=data.frame(wd=pol.noex$t, ws=pol.noex$r), 
cols="jet", paddle=F)#also accurate, dominant direction is ~ 220°
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found my error, template is an argument of CIRCULAR, not of WINDROSE:

windrose(data.frame(dir=circular(pol.ex$t, units="degrees", template="geographics"), 
   mag=pol.ex$r)) #this worked

Thank you.